# Adjoint for a non-densely defined unbounded operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let  $\mathbf{H}$ be a Hilbert space, and $D$ an unbounded densely-defined operator on  $\mathbf{H}$. As is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensions_of_symmetric_operators), every such operator admits an adjoint, with domain possibly different from that of $D$.

Is it possible to define an adjoint for a non-densely defined operator?

Comment: Are you asking about how the usual definition breaks down in this case, or are you asking about possible alternate definitions that might work instead?

Comment: I'm asking about alternate definitions

Comment: I guess one sort of trivial approach is to consider the operator $DP$ where $P$ is orthogonal projection onto the closure of $\operatorname{dom D}$.  In other words, extend your operator by zero on $(\operatorname{dom} D)^\perp$.  Now $DP$ is densely defined and you may consider its adjoint in the usual sense, which formally should equal $PD^*$.

Comment: The issue when $D$ is not densely defined is that, since $D^* x$ is only defined via its inner product with elements of $\operatorname{dom} D$, it is only well defined up to adding something from $(\operatorname{dom} D)^\perp$.  But there is a "natural" choice of what to add, namely 0.